# Adding Java Class Constructor To An ArrayList (extends)

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

I'm not very good at English, but I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do.
So I have this class constructor here:

```
public class God {

public static ArrayList<God> gods = new ArrayList<God>();

private String name;
private PowerType powerType;
private AttackType attackType;
private ArrayList<ItemStack> abilities;
private Pantheon pantheon;
private GodClass godClass;
private List<Pro> pros;
private int favorCost;
private int gemCost;

public enum Pro {
    HIGH_SINGLE_TARGET_DAMAGE, HIGH_MOBILITY, HIGH_AREA_DAMAGE, HIGH_CROWD_CONTROL, HIGH_DEFENSE, HIGH_SUSTAIN, PUSHER, HIGH_ATTACK_SPEED, HIGH_MOVEMENT_SPEED, GREAT_JUNGLER, MEDIUM_CROWD_CONTROL,
}

public enum GodClass {
    ASSASSIN, GUARDIAN, HUNTER, MAGE, WARRIOR
}

public enum Pantheon {
    CHINESE, EGYPTIAN, GREEK, HINDU, MAYAN, NORSE, ROMAN
}

public enum PowerType {
    PHYSICAL, MAGICAL
}

public enum AttackType {
    MELEE, RANGED
}

private int health;
private int mana;
private int speed;
private int range;
private double attackSpeed;
private int damage;
private int physicalProtection;
private int magicalProtection;
private int hp5;
private int mp5;

public God(String name, PowerType powerType, AttackType attackType,
        ArrayList<ItemStack> abilities, Pantheon pantheon,
        GodClass godClass, List<Pro> pros, int favorCost, int gemCost,
        int health, int mana, int speed, int range, double attackSpeed,
        int damage, int physicalProtection, int magicalProtection, int hp5,
        int mp5) {
    this.name = name;
    this.powerType = powerType;
    this.attackType = attackType;
    this.abilities = abilities;
    this.pantheon = pantheon;
    this.godClass = godClass;
    this.pros = pros;
    this.favorCost = favorCost;
    this.gemCost = gemCost;
    this.health = health;
    this.mana = mana;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.range = range;
    this.attackSpeed = attackSpeed;
    this.damage = damage;
    this.physicalProtection = physicalProtection;
    this.magicalProtection = magicalProtection;
    this.hp5 = hp5;
    this.mp5 = mp5;
    gods.add(this);
}
```

This is okay for now, right?
If not, correct me please...
So let's suppose this is okay, I created some classes that extends the constructor `God` which are `Vulcan, Loki and Athena`

```
public class Vulcan extends God {

private Vulcan(String name, PowerType powerType, AttackType attackType,
        ArrayList<ItemStack> abilities, Pantheon pantheon,
        GodClass godClass, ArrayList<Pro> pros, int favorCost, int gemCost,
        int health, int mana, int speed, int range, double attackSpeed,
        int damage, int physicalProtection, int magicalProtection, int hp5,
        int mp5) {
    super("VULCAN", PowerType.MAGICAL, AttackType.RANGED, abilities,
            Pantheon.ROMAN, GodClass.MAGE, Arrays.asList(
                    Pro.HIGH_AREA_DAMAGE, Pro.PUSHER), 5500, 200, 380, 245,
            360, 55, 0.9, 34, 13, 30, 7, 5);
}
```

So now `Vulcan` class is going to be added to the `gods` ArrayList, right? correct me if I'm wrong.
Okay so when I print the list `gods`, I get an empty ArrayList.
Did I do something wrong? Or do I have to define the classes `Vulcan, Loki and Athena`? I'm really confused, help please.

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi Okay, posted real code.

Comment: Check the answers below. You should only have one class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `John, Michael and Levi`, it seems to me that they should be an instance of the class `Human` rather than completely different classes.

Probably you need something like this, but not sure :

```
public Human {
    public static ArrayList<Human> humans = new ArrayList<Human>();

    private String name;
    private int old;

    public Human(String name, int old) {
        this.name = name;
        this.old = old;
        humans.add(this);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Human john = new Human("John", 21);
        Human michael = new Human("Michael", 31);
        Human levi = new Human("Levi", 41);

        System.out.println(Human.humans.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, makes sense! Thank you Habibi.

Answer (score 1):

It would make much sense to have John, Levi and Michael as an instance of Human class.

```
Human john = new Human( "John", 23 );
Human levi = new Human( "Levi", 24 );
Human michael = new Human( "Michael", 25 );
```

Answer (score -1):

This code can use to pass values to super class constructor by using `super()` statement on `class John`.

```
class John extends Human {

public John(String name, int old) {
    super(name, old);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new John("John", 23);
    new John("Michael", 31);
    new John("Levi", 41);

}
}
```